# Copy a external css file into web-app css folder in grails

Tags: css, grails, environment-variables

I have an external css file which I need to read at the gsp page.

I have created a environment variable as "SAM_THEME".

In my bootstrap.groovy file I have read the external css file path.

```
 def init = { servletContext ->
  String SAM_THEME=System.getenv("SAM_THEME");
print "VCAP_SERVICES"+SAM_THEME;
    servletContext["customcss"] =SAM_THEME;

 }
```

How when I try to access the servlet context in the gsp page.I am able to get the external css file path, but it is not getting read by the grails application.

```
       <link rel="stylesheet"
href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: application.customcss)}"
type="text/css">
```

Since this method is not working,there is any other way of to copy the external css file directly into web-app/css folder while bootstrap so that i can access directly in my gsp page.

Answer (score 0):

In your BootStrap you can get the path to the css folder:

```
class BootStrap {

  def init = { servletContext ->
    println new File(servletContext.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/css")).getAbsolutePath();
  }
}
```

Then just copy your file to that location.